# Show a different logo to logged in users

Tags: wordpress

How to show a different logo or maybe a different header.php to logged in users, preferably excluding the admins. I am working on a WordPress site and wish to display a different logo (or a another header.php) to logged in members only.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [is_user_logged_in()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) function.

In your template like:

```
<?php // yourtemplate.php

if (is_admin()) :
    get_header('admin'); // for admin use: header-admin.php
elseif (is_user_logged_in()) :
    get_header('user'); // for logged in user use: header-user.php
else :
    get_header(); // guest or everything else
endif;

// content here
// footer here
// etc
```

Comment: Thanks @error overflow. I implemented this for a logo and it really works. However, if there a way to show a different logo/header page wise.. I mean I want to show on example.com/this_page and all other pages nested under this_page. Hopefully there must be workaround. thanks again